# Is it okay to take basis from rref matrix as well as original matrix in both column space and row space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $A$ be the given matrix of order $m \times n$.

I want to find the basis for both row and column spaces of $A$.

I transformed the matrix A in to its row reduced echelon form i.e., $rref(A)$.

Then, in general, for row space, vectors are taken from the $rref(A)$ and for the column space, vectors are taken from the actual matrix $A$.

My doubt is can I take the vectors for basis of row space from the actual matirx and column space basis from the $rref(A)$?

Comment: How do you know which of the original rows are linearly independent?

Answer (score 2):

You can take the vectors for basis of row space from the actual matrix. But you can't take the vectors for basis of column space from the $\text{rref}(A)$. When you do elementary operations on the rows of $A$ to get $\text{rref}(A)$ you form an inversible matrix $O$ such that
$$
OA = \text{rref}(A)
$$
and you can easily show that
$$
\text{Null}(OA) = \text{Null}(A) = \text{Null}(\text{rref}(A)).
$$
But in general we don't have
$$
\text{Im}(OA) = \text{Im}(A).
$$
See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/703833/669687) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the matrix:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 0 & 2\\-2 & -5 & 1 & -1\\0 & -3 & 3 & 4\\ 3 & 6 & 0 & -7\end{pmatrix}.$$

Its reduced row echelon form is:

$$\tilde A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 2 & 0\\0 & 1 & -1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Now suppose you had chosen the basis $\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}\}$ for the column space of $A$. This would be wrong as $\begin{pmatrix}1\\-2\\0\\3\end{pmatrix}$ being a column of $A$ is in the column space but clearly no linear combination of the basis vectors equals it (no combination can create the $3$ in the last entry).

Answer (score 1):

Elementary row operations change the column space of the matrix, so you always have to go back to the original matrix to find a basis for its column space. A simple example is $$\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$$ with RREF $$\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$ The column space of the original matrix is obviously spanned by $(1,1)^T$, but that clearly doesn’t lie in the column space of its RREF.

On the other hand, elementary row operations don’t change the row space of a matrix: if $Ax\ne0$ and $R$ is invertible, then $RAx\ne0$. Now, there’s certainly *some* subset of the rows of the original matrix that forms a basis for its row space. The problem is that the RREF doesn’t help you find it. By definition, the nonzero rows of the RREF are always linearly independent, so those first $r$ rows of the RREF form a basis for the row space. The first $r$ rows of the original matrix, on the other hand, might not even be linearly independent. A simple example of this is $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$ with RREF $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$