# Why is the solution set of the reduced row echelon form of A equal to the solution set of A?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

One way of solving a system of linear equations is to express it in an augmented matrix. Then, we can perform elementary row operations in order to bring the matrix into RREF (reduced row echelon form), and from there, we can find the solutions of the initial system.  [A lot of sources take this solution set equvalence fact as granted](https://www.math.hmc.edu/calculus/tutorials/linearsystems/linearsystems.pdf). But why are the solutions to RREF(**A**) the same as the solutions to **A**?

I think another way of asking this is: why does row equivalence imply two matrices will have the same solution set?

Comment: Think about the effect of left-multiplying both sides of the equation by an invertible matrix.

Comment: If you're comfortable with matrix multiplication, then I would say that it's clear that $Ax = 0 \iff RAx = 0$ for any invertible matrix $R$ (i.e. an $R$ that implements a succession of row-operations on $A$)

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I think you make it too general though, I don't think that we can multiply by *any* invertible matrix and still get the same solution set. In particular @Omnomnomnom, yours seems true for the null space, but what about for any b, b$\neq$ 0?

Comment: So far, this is the best (albeit rather non-rigorous) answer to my question: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~linear/old/notes3.pdf

The gist is that if we think about what the elementary row operations (EROs ) are doing, they aren't changing the meaning of the system of equations

Comment: If you had an inhomogeneous system $Ax=b$, it would be equivalent to $RAx=Rb$ for any invertible $R$. So if you know that row operations amount to left-multiplication by invertible matrices, then @Omnomnomnom has essentially answered your question.

Comment: @AndreasBlass so are you saying that we can multiply by *any* invertible matrix and the image of **A** will be preserved? This source seems to say otherwise: https://tartarus.org/gareth/maths/Linear_Algebra/row_operations.pdf

(row operations preserve only the kernel and row space, while column operations preserve only the image)

Comment: @information_interchange No, the image is not preserved; it has to be multiplied by $R$ also. Note that the equation in my comment is not $RAx=b$ but $RAx=Rb$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the augmented matrix (AM) is just a shorthand way of writing up the full given system, including the right hand side, in its present state. The so-called *elementary operations* transform the originally given system into a system whose solutions can be easily found "by inspection" and little calculation.

Now these elementary operations have been invented for the very reason that they do not change the set ${\cal L}$ of solutions in any way. This is obvious for multiplying an equation, resp., the corresponding row of AM, by a nonzero constant, and it is obvious for interchanging two equations, resp., the corresponding rows of  AM. There remains adding $\lambda\>{\rm row}_i$ to ${\rm row}_j$, where $j\ne i$. Since this adding encompasses the RHS of the system as well it is easy to see that any ${\bf x}$ solving the old system also solves the new system. It remains to check that the new system contains no additional solutions. Therefore let ${\bf x}$ be any solution of the new system. Then this ${\bf x}$ will also solve the newnew system obtained by adding $-\lambda\>{\rm row}_i$ to (the new) ${\rm row}_j$. But this newnew system is again the old system; hence ${\bf x}$ is already a solution of the old system.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the most direct answer, and this source seems to confirm it: http://linear.ups.edu/html/section-RREF.html (Theorem EOPSS) I believe overall, the logic goes something like "Elimination allows us to find the solution for an equivalent system of equations, and performing EROs is just doing elimination but with matrics". Hence, EROs preserve the solution set

Comment: Thanks @information_interchange, I found the exact page containing the proof for Theorem EOPSS here: http://linear.pugetsound.edu/html/section-SSLE.html

Comment: awesome, thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you do elementary operations $O_1, \ldots, O_n$ on the rows of $A$ to get $\text{rref}(A)$ you form an inversible matrix $O = O_1 \cdots O_n$ such that
$$
OA = \text{rref}(A)
$$
and let us show that
$$
\text{Null}(OA) = \text{Null}(A) = \text{Null}(\text{rref}(A))
$$
$(\supset)$ Let $X \in \text{Null}(A)$. We have $
AX = 0
$.
Thus
$
OAX=0
$.
Therefore $X \in \text{Null}(OA)$.

$(\subset)$ Let $X \in \text{Null}(OA)$. We have
$$
OAX = 0
$$
by multiplying on both sides by $O^{-1}$, we get
$$
AX=0
$$
Thus $X \in \text{Null}(A)$.

We showed that $\text{rref}(A)$ and $A$ have the same solution set.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why is it sufficient to show that Null(**A**) = Null(rref(**A**)) means the solution set is equivalent? I think I agree with your proof that their null spaces are equivalent, but does that necessarily imply their column spaces are also equivalent?

Comment: @information_interchange Remember that $\text{Null}(A) = \{X \, ; AX =0\}$, so $X$ is solution of the system represented by the matrix $A$ *iff* $X$ is solution of the one represented by the matrix $\text{rref}(A)$. And no, their column spaces are not, in general, equivalent (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3329801/669687)).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But if the column space of **A** and rref(**A**) is not equivalent, then definitely the solution set is not the same! If we cannot say that $Im(A) == Im(rref(A)) $, then I don't think we can conclude that a solution $x$ to $Ax=b$ will be a solution to $rref(A)x=b$