# Why does the method of Row Reduction work in solving systems of equations?

Tags: linear-algebra

How is it that the augmented matrix,
[A│**b**] that represents the equation A**x**=**b** has the same solutions as rref[A│**b**]?

Why does the method of Row Reduction work in solving systems of equations and how does it preserve solutions?

Comment: Performing elementary row operations on $A$ is like multiplying an invertible matrix on the left of $A$.

Comment: Your question doesn't really have enough detail to answer. A matrix doesn't have a set of solutions, but equations do. Are you looking at solving $Ax = 0$? Or $Ax = b$ for arbitrary $b$? Note that $\operatorname{RREF}(A)x = b$ and $Ax = b$ will have different solutions in general. If you could clarify your question, it will be better received.

Comment: That said, have a look at the related questions listed on the right of the page (e.g.[this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3330346/why-is-the-solution-set-of-the-reduced-row-echelon-form-of-a-equal-to-the-soluti)). There have been many variants of this question on this site, and there are plenty of good answers out there.

Comment: For what it's worth, your edit is a substantial improvement. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elementary row operations on $A$ preserve:

1. Row space of A, $Row(A)$, which is a linear span of rows of A, and
2. Linear relations between columns.

A sequence of elementary row operations can be presented by a product of elementary matrices, each of which corresponds to a performed elementary row operation. Suppose this product of matrices is given by $C$. Then the result of elementary row operations applied to $A$ can be written as $A'=CA$. So if originally you have $Ab=0$, then you get $CAb=C0=0$. For instance,

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3\\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
7&8&9
\end{pmatrix}
$ $\rightarrow$ $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 1 & 2 \\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}
$

From the RREF you can see that $\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\
 2 \\
0
\end{pmatrix} = -1\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
 0 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}+2\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
 1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}$. The same linear combination of columns is true in the original matrix $A$: $\begin{pmatrix}
3\\
 6 \\
9
\end{pmatrix} = -1\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
 4 \\
7
\end{pmatrix}+2\begin{pmatrix}
2\\
 5 \\
8
\end{pmatrix}$.

Note that elementary row operations do change column space, $Col(A)$, and linear relations between rows.