# Question about matrices and rref

Tags: linear-algebra

So like I learned that the column space of a matrix A is just the span of all the column vectors, and I also learned that the pivot columns of a matrix A(just the columns with a pivot entry after getting A into rref) are a basis for A. Now I'm just confused kinda how should I really see matrices? Like when I put a matrix into rref I think of the matrix as a set of equations I guess like a coefficient matrix but sometimes I see a matrix as a 1 x n array of column vectors but how do all these relations stay after getting a matrix into rref? Like if A is just an array of column vectors and I put A into rref and there are two pivot entries, these two pivot entries say they're column 1 and 2 then now column 1 and 2 in the original matrix are a basis for the column space. How do this relations stay in the original matrix too? This is kinda hard to explain but I hope someone can understand my question

Just to clarify again I'll kinda make a TLDR: If I have a matrix A and assume rref(A) = B then we know that basis(C(a)) = pivot columns of B how exactly does this relation work? What can I see a matrix as for it to make sense? Like if I view a matrix as an array of column vectors what even is getting it into rref doing to the column vectors? doesn't even really make sense to me. And if I view it as an array of column vectors how does the relation for the pivot columns hold for the original matrix too? They're different vectors and stuff

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand all parts of your question correctly, but my contribution is too long for a comment. I might add or update my post in case your replies reveal that I misinterpreted some of your statements/questions.

Let's start with how I try to view matrices:
I try to see a matrix as a table containing some numbers. Depending on the context, these numbers get some meaning, for example if the matrix should represent a linear map $\xi:~ V \rightarrow W$, then the matrix $A$ is the representation matrix of $\xi$ with respect to some bases in $V$ and $W$.

What do the columns of this matrix mean now?
The image of the matrix is a linear combination of it's column vectors. That's exactly what happens if you multiply a vector $v$ from the right onto $A$ (insert a vector $v$ into the map $\xi$).

> So like I learned that the column space of a matrix A is just the span of all the column vectors, and I also learned that the pivot columns of a matrix A(just the columns with a pivot entry after getting A into rref) are a basis for A.

I think you have to be a little careful with the terminology;
A matrix does not have a basis, vector spaces have bases.

> How do this relations stay in the original matrix too?

I am not exactly sure what you mean with this question, as it sounds you described the concept correctly. Therefore, I try to summarize:
When you bring a matrix into rref you change it. The matrix in the end is obviously not the same as in the beginning, it is just equivalent wrt. elementary transformations. In the new form, it is easier to read out which columns are linearly independent from its rref form, but it is not the representation of the linear map any more. The spaces might have remained the same, but the bases are not. So, when take a look at the pivot columns of $A$ it tells you which columns of the original matrix are linearly independent (Mind to keep track in case you swapped columns while bringing $A$ into its rref form!)

Let's look at an example. For the matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1&2\\3&4\end{pmatrix} $ one can easily check that $\text{rref}(A) = \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$. Note that $A$ maps from $V = \mathbb{R}^2$ to $W=\mathbb{R}^2$.

The matrix $A$ has the column vectors $\begin{pmatrix}1\\3\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}2\\4\end{pmatrix}$ hence maps
$$A\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}1\\3\end{pmatrix}$$
$$A\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}2\\4\end{pmatrix}$$

The matrix $\text{rref}(A)$ has the column vectors $\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$ hence represents the identity map.

You can view the original matrix $A$ therefore as representation of the identity map, where you chose the canonical bases for both $V$ and $W$, while $\text{rref}(A)$ is a representation wrt. the canonical basis in $V$ and the basis $B_W = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix}1\\3\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}2\\4\end{pmatrix}\right\}$.
If you like so, finding the rref of $A$ can be interpreted of finding a represetation of the same linear map $\xi$ with respect to another bases. Keep in mind that representation matrices of linear maps are only defined with respect to bases of the origin and image space.

I hope this helps to clarify the confusion and/or improve your intuition.

Comment: Kinda helped but like here I was reading something: The solutions of the homogeneous equations Ax = 0 and Bx = 0 are the same. Therefore, the relations
among the columns of A and B are the same. (Any non-zero solution of these homogeneous equations gives
a relation among these columns.) I just still don't really get WHY this makes the relations among the columns of A and B have to be the same? Like yea they have the same solutions but I still don't see why that makes the relations among the columns of both matrices the same? Like that if column 1 and 2 are independent in B then

Comment: they'll also be independent in A like I don't get how they'll be related

Comment: Yes, the solutions of the homogenous equations are the same! This is because $Ax=0$ means $x$ is in the kernel of $A$, so is mapped onto the zero vector. The zero vector has the same representation wrt. every basis in $W$ (if the zero vector could be expressed in any other way than by choosing all coordinates zero, we wouldn't have a basis!).

For the second part: What exactly do you mean by "gives a relation among these columns"? Which relation do you mean?

Comment: @jayblosem11 [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702618/understanding-the-significance-of-row-space-and-column-space-basis/703833#703833) might be illuminating.